# Translating a code example from c# into c++

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm rtrying to translate the following from the following example
[SplitContainer Splitter Gets Focus Rectangle?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9c5780cd-fa3e-4b83-afd8-592a8b4cd83a)

```
private: Control getFocused(Control::ControlCollection controls)
{
    //foreach (Control c in controls)
    //{
    //  if (c.Focused)
    //  {
    //      // Return the focused control
    //      return c;
    //  }
    //  else if (c.ContainsFocus)
    //  {
    //      // If the focus is contained inside a control's children
    //      // return the child
    //      return getFocused(c.Controls);
    //  }
    //}
    do
    {
            if (c.Focused)
            {
                // Return the focused control
                return c;
            }
            else if (c.ContainsFocus)
            {
                // If the focus is contained inside a control's children
                // return the child
                return getFocused(c.Controls);
            }
    }
    while(Control c in controls);
   // No control on the form has focus
   return null;
}
```

i'm looking for the right synthanx for the DO WHILE loop

```
while(Control c in controls); // error
```

and since the function '`private: Control getFocused(Control::ControlCollection controls)`' is of the type Control, i need to specify a return value, both '`return null;`' and '`return nullptr;`' fail!

EDIT:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= controls.Count; index++)
        {
            if(controls[index]->Focused)
            {
                return controls[index];
            }
            else if (controls[index]->ContainsFocus)
            {
                return getFocused(controls[index]->Controls);
            }
        }
```

`return controls[index];` -> *no suitable user-defined conversion from "System::Windows::Forms::Control ^" to "System::Windows::Forms::Control" exists.*

`return getFocused(controls[index]->Controls);` -> *function "getFocused" cannot be called with the given argument list argument types are: (System::Windows::Forms::Control::ControlCollection ^)*

`return null;` -> *identifier "null" is undefined*

or

`return nullptr;` ->    *no suitable user-defined conversion from "decltype(nullptr)" to "System::Windows::Forms::Control" exists*

Comment: did you ever use google to search for a code or syntax ? i just googled do---while in c++ and found MSDN reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0kk5few(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yeah, i did ... but ... it's mostly the default tutorial with the standart operators

Comment: You don't have `foreach(.. in ..)` syntax in C++. You have to use a normal `for` loop using indexes to access items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My C++/CLI is a little bit rusty. But let me give this a whack:

```
private: Control ^ getFocused(Control::ControlCollection ^controls)
{
    for each (Control ^c in controls)
    {
        if (c->Focused)
        {
            return c;
        }
        else if (c->ContainsFocus)
        {
            return getFocused(c->Controls);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `Control '^' getFocused(Control::ControlCollection ^controls)`
this did the trick adding the '^' in front of the method ... making a function pointer?

Comment: You're not making a function pointer, you're passing and returning the CLR object by their handle (which is done automatically in C#, but must be explicit in C++/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

MD.Unicorn is technically correct in that there is not C++ syntax for "foreach". However C++ does include something very similar in the STL (think .net framework rather than C# proper).

[C++ STL for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

```
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [=](Control control){
    //Stuff
});
```

Comment: i know the 'for each' loop is no c++ synthax, that why i asked the question.

Comment: Erm...sigh...What I was saying is that in C++ its not IN the language, its IN the STANDARD LIBRARIES. Which is so damned standard that its only TECHNICALLY not a part of the language.

Comment: This is THE CORRECT syntax for STL:for_each. Which doesn't answer your question persay. But just solves your problem instead.

Comment: it might, if i was coding on win32 ... but i'm using dotnot